# pandas join remove columns if the same

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` that I want to join based on their column `'C'`

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[1,0,2,4],[2,3,1,3]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[2,2,2,4],[3,4,1,3]],columns=['A','F','C','D'])

    df1
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  4
1  2  3  1  3

   df2
   A  F  C  D
0  2  2  2  4
1  3  4  1  3

# Merge the dataframes
dataframe_matched = df1.join(
    other=df2.set_index('C'),
    on='C',
    how="inner",
    lsuffix="_left",
    rsuffix="_right",
    sort=True,
)


dataframe_matched
   A_left  B  C  D_left  A_right  F  D_right
1       2  3  1       3        3  4        3
0       1  0  2       4        2  2        4
```

The columns `D_left` and `D_right` are the same.
Is there an easy way to keep only 1 with the original name?

```
dataframe_matched
   A_left  B  C       D  A_right  F
1       2  3  1       3        3  4
0       1  0  2       4        2  2
```

Comment: If you know for sure they are the same, why not join on `C` and `D`?

Comment: As quang suggested, merge on both `df1.merge(df2, on=['C', 'D'], suffixes=['_left', '_right'])`

Comment: I don't know that they are the same upfront...

Answer (score 1):

You can do `drop_duplicates`

```
df1.merge(df2,on='C').T.drop_duplicates().T
Out[288]: 
   A_x  B  C  D_x  A_y  F
0    1  0  2    4    2  2
1    2  3  1    3    3  4
```

Update

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('C'),df2.set_index('C')],1,keys=['right','left']).\
   T.reset_index(level=1).\
     drop_duplicates().set_index('level_1',append=True).T
Out[337]: 
        right       left   
level_1     A  B  D    A  F
C                          
2           1  0  4    2  2
1           2  3  3    3  4
```

Comment: This could potentially, although unlikely, to drop some other columns, e.g. `A` == `D`.